# Green's function of $\vec\nabla\otimes\vec\nabla$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

Consider the following vector differential equation
$$\vec\nabla\cdot(\vec\nabla \vec F(\vec x)) = \vec S(\vec x)\,.$$
We can write this equation as an operator equation
$$D[\vec F] = \vec S\,,$$
where
$$D = \vec\nabla\otimes\vec\nabla\,,$$
where $\otimes$ is the outer product.
Since this equation is a linear differential equation, it seems natural to go to Fourier space, where it becomes
$$\tilde D\tilde F = \tilde S\,,$$
and
$$\tilde D =-\vec k\otimes\vec k\,.$$
However, $\tilde D$ appears to be singular... Any suggestions for how to `invert' this operator?

Edit: Perhaps there is a way to project out the singular subspace?

Comment: In components, is $D_{ij}=\partial_i \partial_j$?

Comment: Yep exactly. Also I think I understand what to do - I'll write it out in my question.

Comment: Actually, I'm still confused haha...

Comment: Given $\partial_{i}\partial_jF_j=S_i$, let $\phi=\partial_j F_j$ so $\partial_i \phi =S_i$ which may be integrated to find $\phi$. From this it looks like $S$ may not be specified completely arbitrarily, and once $\phi$ is determined, $F$ is unconstrained: there remains one DE with many undetermined functions $F_j$. Perhaps this changes if you only look at solutions for which the partial derivatives do not commute... What is the source of this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your help! It is a problem that came up when I was computing the Green's function of electromagnetism. I realize now that adding any (non-singular) diagonal operator to D makes it non-singular as well. I had just gotten myself confused about how to invert the whole operator (which is D + d'Alembertian) and focused on trying to first invert D.